# Toggle disabled attribute of paper-button

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `paper-button` (send button) which is related to multiple `paper-input` fields/element.
The `paper-input` button should be disabled as long as the user fills out all related `paper-input` fields/elements (**newEmail** and **passwd**).

This is the important part of the element

```
  <gold-email-input id="newEmail"
                    label="Email"
                    no-label-float required>
  </gold-email-input>

  <paper-input id="passwd"
               type="password"
               label="Password"
               no-label-float required>
  </paper-input>

  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus
                  disabled$="[[isInputEmpty($$.newEmail.value, $$.passwd.value)]]"
                  on-tap="changeEmail"
                  class="default">Save</paper-button>
  </div>
```

The function **disabled$="[[isInputEmpty($$.newEmail.value, $$.passwd.value)]]"** won't be called when the newEmail.value or passdw.value change.

This is the JavaScript part:

```
  isInputEmpty (email, pass) {
    if (email.length === 0 || pass.length === 0) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

What's the correct implementation to toggle the attribute **disabled** between *true* and *false*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `disabled` is actually a [property of `<paper-button>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button#property-disabled) (not an attribute), so you should *not* be using the [attribute-binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) (i.e., `$=`).

   ```
   <!-- don't do this -->
   <!--
   <paper-button disabled$="[[isInputEmpty(...)]]">
   -->

   <paper-button disabled="[[isInputEmpty(...)]]">
   ```
2. You're attempting to pass the values of `newEmail` and `passwd` in your binding, but you're not using the correct syntax. You'll have to bind the values from those inputs into properties that you would pass as arguments in your computed binding:

   ```
   <gold-email-input value="{{email}}"></gold-email-input>
   <paper-input value="{{password}}"></paper-input>
   <paper-button disabled="[[isInputEmpty(email, password)]]"></paper-button>
   ```